# How to Disable Web Security in CefSharp3

Tags: c#, google-chrome, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp3 to embed a chrome browser into my C#.Net application. Everything loads well and works as would in the chrome browser, but the both the `disable-web-security` command line setting or BrowserSettings.WebSecurity setting stops the embedded browser from preventing me to load scripts from a different origin.

Error message: "Refused to load script...because it violates CSP (Content Security Policy)..."

I thought disabling the setting above disable CSP.

Here is the `chrome://version` output from the same window/browser:

```
    CEF 3.2704.1432.g60b3718
    Chromium    51.0.2704.103
    OS  Windows
    WebKit  537.36
    JavaScript  5.1.281.65
    Flash
    User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
    Command Line    "c:\my_path\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\My_Solution\My_Project\bin\x64\Debug\My_Project.vshost.exe" --browser-subprocess-path=CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --log-file="c:\my_path\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\My_Solution\My_Project\bin\x64\Debug\debug.log" --remote-debugging-port=8088 --enable-system-flash=1 --process-per-tab=1 --allow-access-from-files=1 --allow-universal-access-from-files=1 --disable-web-security=1 --no-proxy-server=1
    Module Path c:\my_path\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\My_Solution\My_Project\bin\x64\Debug\libcef.dll
Cache Path  cache
```

From the above, `--disable-web-security=1` shows is set, but still CSP is active, how can I make this work to disable CSP?

I've looked at other questions on this forum, but I did not find the case where the setting does not get effected.

Comment: Search http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php from what I remember, CSP is separate to web security.

Comment: For reference http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14298&hilit=modify+response&start=10#p31443